# Labeling the features of a geojson map: how to control the location of the lables

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have greatly simplified the code, but the issue remains.

I have a geoJSON map with a feature for each county. I want to label the counties with the county name, which is available in properties. I do this by adding code to the OnEachFeature method. The locations of the labels is wrong and does not change when the map is zoomed.

Here is my code:

```
    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        container = L.DomUtil.get('label-container')
        coords = feature.geometry.coordinates[0][0];
        coords2 = [coords[1],coords[0]];
        container.innerHTML = "label";
        var pos = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.latLng(coords2));
        op = new L.Point(pos.x,pos.y);
        L.DomUtil.setPosition(container, op);

        layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        });
    }
```